Recursive definition for sign of permutation
Does anyone know of a more-formal reference for the following recursive definition of the sign of a permutation?
Define $\epsilon_n: S_n \rightarrow \{1,-1\}$ recursively by letting $\varepsilon_1$ be the trivial homomorphism and for $n \geq 1$
$$\varepsilon_{n+1}(\sigma)= \begin{cases} \varepsilon_n(\sigma) & \text{ if } \sigma \in S_n \\
-\varepsilon_n((n+1 \text{ } s) \circ \sigma) & \text{ if } \sigma \notin S_n \text{ with } \sigma(n+1) = s \end{cases}$$
(from this answer.)
It is highly related to theorems 4.3.23 and 4.3.26 in this (pdf), but those notes do not actually define the sign in terms of the minimum number of transpositions that those theorems discuss.
The standard definition of the sign of a permutation seems to be in terms of inversion counting (or the related Vandermonde polynomial), but this definition seems simpler to me.
